# Can't compile plugin builder plugin in QGIS 2.4 (Windows)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

I'm trying to build a basic plugin using plugin builder but I can't even compile it. I tried following a few tutorials and just trying to compile whatever but that always results in the same problem.

Error messages for rcc4.exe and uic4.bin:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS Chugiak\bin\pyrcc4" -o my_plugin.py my_plugin_dialog_base.ui
No resources in resource description.   

"C:\Program Files\QGIS Chugiak\bin\pyuic4" -o my_plugin.py my_plugin_dialog_base.ui
ImportError: No module named site
```

relevant files in the plugin folder:

```
my_plugin.py
my_plugin_dialog.py
my_plugin_dialog_base.ui
resources.qrc
```

What's in the /bin folder:

```
pyrcc4.exe
pyuic4.bat
pyuic4.bat.tmpl
```

Any idea what's wrong? I'm limited to using whatever's installed with QGIS to compile this, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to run

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

The .ui file is loaded dynamically in the recent versions of the default plugin code. For example, if the plugin is called test, the corresponding GUI loading code in test_dialog.py is

```
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
   os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_dialog_base.ui'))
```

All necessary instructions are provided in the Plugin Builder popup which appears after the plugin is created.

Comment: Thanks - I actually followed one of your guides ( http://anitagraser.com/2014/04/26/getting-started-writing-qgis-2-x-plugins/). You mentioned running `pyuic4 -o ui_buildertest.py ui_buildertest.ui` first. I also was a bit confused that nothing indicated that the process was successful. Just two points you might want to consider if you decide to update your guide (which was quite helpful).

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm coming a bit late, but a quicker way to do this (provided that you're using Windows), is by using the OSGeo4W Shell. Make command will work from there.

[Source](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2015-January/030543.html) and I've also tested it QGIS version 2.8.1 if that adds any more relevance.

Best regards,