# Can't execute plugin made by Plugin Builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have read this post: 
[Can't compile plugin builder plugin in QGIS 2.4 (Windows)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137095/cant-compile-plugin-builder-plugin-in-qgis-2-4-windows/187459?noredirect=1#comment282604_187459)

But I couldn't resolve my problem.

I have already seen this post, looking for help. I can execute:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

But when I want to open my plugin made by Plugin Builder, it displays an error, saying that it is "broken".

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the `make` command for your plugin and then restarting QGIS?

Comment: My OSGeo4W Shell doesn't recognise that command, that is why I am so dissapointed... :( I don't know what to do about that. I have tried to execute pb_tool but in my windows shell, I don't think it is going to recognise the code in the examples of the help documentation about pb_tool

Comment: Strange, maybe try reinstalling QGIS again using the **OSGeo4W Network Installer**? I recently had to reinstall QGIS (about 3 weeks ago) and the `make` method is still recognised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your plugin doesn't have a `metadata.txt` file, could you have a look at the plugin folder to check if such file is present?

Make sure all your plugin files are inside your plugin folder, which in turn should be inside `python/plugins/` folder, like this:

```
qgis2/
...python/
......plugins/
.........NPlugin/
............metadata.txt
............__init_.py
............icon.png
............(and all other files)
```

Sometimes, one can make a mistake and create an extra folder while choosing the directory to save the plugin, like this:

```
qgis2/
...python/
......plugins/
.........NPlugin/
............NPlugin/
...............metadata.txt
...............__init_.py
...............icon.png
...............(and all other files)
```

Note the double `NPlugin` folder (`python/plugins/NPlugin/Nplugin/...`), which will make QGIS not to load the plugin. If that's your case, just leave a single `NPlugin` folder, from which QGIS can access all plugin files (such as in the first directory structure I mentioned).

If, on the contrary, your directory structure is fine, your plugin is missing a `metadata` file. Create a new file `metadata.txt` inside you plugin folder, containing information like:

```
# This file contains metadata for your plugin.         
[general]
name=My Plugin
qgisMinimumVersion=2.0
description=My plugin does a lot of things
version=0.1
author=Me
email=me@mycompany.co

about=Plugin to do a lot of things

tracker=http://www.mycompany.co/tracker
repository=http://www.mycompany.co/git

# Tags are comma separated with spaces allowed
tags=GIS,Raster

homepage=http://www.mycompany.co/
category=Plugins
icon=icon.png
# experimental flag
experimental=True

# deprecated flag (applies to the whole plugin, not just a single version)
deprecated=False
```

Restart QGIS (or reload your plugin) and you should now get your plugin loaded.

Comment: +1, great answer! I will be writing a plugin soon so will definitely need to keep this in mind!

Comment: Just tried to create a test plugin and it happened to me, I created a double folder for my plugin, so I got the same error. Let's hope that solves the problem.

Comment: I have changed the folder, and made the resources_rc.py. Metadata is available. Then, I closed QGIS and opened again. I got this error again: 
No module named resources

Comment: Ok, that's another question. Your plugin (as it was created via Plugin Builder) expects the resources file to be named 'resources.py'. Try with such name.

Comment: I used 

pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc

and it worked. Thanks very much to everybody !!!