# Unable to compile plugin (pyqt) for Qgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I have installed the

- latest version of Qgis (2.18.0, 64 bit) using the OSGeo4W  network
  installer from the download page of Qgis.
- QT 5.7.0 (64 bit) available at
  https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2

Next, created a code using the 'plugin builder' in Qgis and then compiled  in the OSGeo4W Shell (screen shot attached)

---

pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc

---

[image: Code compile]

Next, restarted Qgis but was the plugin was not loaded. The log file displayed the following

[image: Log file]

I have no coding background and therefore unable to understand and resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you use the plugin builder plugin?

Comment: yes, the plugin was created using the 'plugin builder'

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Can't execute plugin made by Plugin Builder](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187461/cant-execute-plugin-made-by-plugin-builder)

Comment: I have confirmed that the plugin is in the ' root plugin folder' (no nesting of folder names) and the plugin has a correct metadata text file---- with all this I still I do not have the 'make' method and the error remains.